# JS: Random String without Repeating Same String Twice

Tags: javascript, string, random

I'm trying to figure out a way to pull a random string from an array with pure JS, without the same string appearing twice in succession.

I'm using a random number (`random number`) to pull a random string from `randomMsg` using the random number's index, I'm then storing it in `currentMsg`.

On click, I'm then redefining the `currentMsg` with a new random string. I'm then using an `if`/`else` statement to see if our `prevMsg` is equal to `currentMsg`, if it is (which it isn't on first click), I'm using another `if`/`else` statement to increment or decrement our index, so it returns a unique string (`anotherMsg`) to our HTML and sets `prevMsg` var to that string.

Else, it returns the `currentMsg` to our HTML, and sets `prevMsg` equal to `currentMsg`.

Fucntion below:

```
(function message() {
    var ranNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0);
    var randomMsg = [
      "string one",
      "string two",
      "string three",
      "string four",
      "string five"
    ];

    var currentMsg = randomMsg[Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0)];
    var prevMsg = "";

    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = currentMsg;

    document.getElementById("intro").onclick = function() {
        var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0);
        currentMsg = randomMsg[ranNum];
        if(prevMsg == currentMsg) {
            var anotherMsg = "";
            if(ranNum >= 0 && ranNum < 4) {
                anotherMsg = randomMsg[ranNum + 1];
            }
            else {
                anotherMsg = randomMsg[ranNum - 1];
            }
            document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = anotherMsg;
            prevMsg = anotherMsg; // set prevMsg to anotherMsg
        } else {
            document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = currentMsg;
            prevMsg = currentMsg; // set prevMsg to currentMsg
        };
    };
})();
```

I've also setup a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/realph/ygx3vh0q/).

While it works, I'm eager to now if there's a more elegant approach to write such a function. Also I'm replacing the entire string, is it better to replace just the word (one, two, three, etc.) or doesn't that matter one bit?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because "*it works,*" and your question is for review, I'd suggest asking this over on [codereview.se], rather than here on [so].

Answer (score 2):

For **readability** and **generic** reason, the **array** should stand **outside** the **function**:

```
var msg = [
    "string one",
    "string two",
    "string three",
    "string for",
    "string five",
    "string six" /* add as many values as you want */
];
```

A function that returns a **random number**, but **not** the **current** **random number**:

```
function randWithout(n, arr) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (i !== n) {
            res.push(i);
        }
    }
    return res[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))];
}
```

Arr must be an argument of the function, because the **length** of the array is needed. Further a function that returns a random number:

```
function randNumber(arr) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return rand;
}
```

The last function:

```
(function message() {
    var intro = document.getElementById("intro");
    var currNumber = randNumber(msg);
    intro.innerHTML = msg[currNumber];
    var clickNumber = randWithout(currNumber, msg);
    intro.onclick = function () {
        intro.innerHTML = msg[clickNumber];
        clickNumber = randWithout(clickNumber, msg);
    }
})()
```

**Plain** and **readable**!

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amwiom/L6zanfqo/)

Comment: Thank you for this. Very simple to understand. I can't work out what `return res[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))];` is doing though – could you explain?

Comment: In the `function randWithout`, you push all the indices from the array (here msg), **except** the index from the **current number**, into the result array. The length is `arr.length - 1`. Here the msg array has the length 6, the length from the result array must be 5. For example `res = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]`. The current number here is 2. We don' t want this as the number immediately afterwards. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)` a random number from (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). `res[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))]` for example `res[3]` which is from [0, 1, 3, 4, 5] 4.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of randomly pulling a string from the array, shuffle the array and pull the strings out in sequence.

```
randomMsg.sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5}); // shuffle
```

If you want to keep the original order of `randomMsg` just `.slice()` it into another array:

```
var shuffedMsg = randomMsg.slice().sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5});
```

Just like shuffling a deck of cards, you may shuffle more than once to mix it some more. But calling `.sort()` like the examples above gets tedious. So wrap it in a function:

```
function shuffle (arr) {
    return arr..sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5});
}

var shuffledMsg = shuffle(shuffle(shuffle(randomMsg.slice())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did away with anotherMsg, one if clause, and used the ternary operator:

```
(function message() {
    var currentMsg, prevMsg;
    var ranNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0);
    var randomMsg = [
      "string one",
      "string two",
      "string three",
      "string four",
      "string five"
    ];
    prevMsg = (prevMsg) ? prevMsg : "";
    var currentMsg = randomMsg[ranNumber];
    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = currentMsg;

    document.getElementById("intro").onclick = function() {
        var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0);
        currentMsg = randomMsg[ranNum];
        if(prevMsg === currentMsg) {
            ranNum = (ranNum === 4) ? 0 : ranNum++;
            currentMsg = randomMsg[ranNumber];
        } 
    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = currentMsg;
    prevMsg = currentMsg;       
};
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Added another tmpMsg, on click move message to tmpMsg, on next iteration merge back to randomMsg and move the latest displayed message to tmpMsg.

```
    (function message() {
    var randomMsg = [
        "string one",
        "string two",
        "string three",
        "string four",
        "string five"
    ];

    var random = function() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * (randomMsg.length)) + 0);
    }

    var tmpMsg;
    var ranNumber = random();

    var currentMsg = randomMsg[ranNumber];

    tmpMsg = randomMsg.splice(ranNumber, 1)[0];

    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = currentMsg;

    document.getElementById("intro").onclick = function() {
        ranNumber = random();
        currentMsg = randomMsg[ranNumber];
        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = currentMsg;
        randomMsg.push(tmpMsg);
        tmpMsg = randomMsg.splice(ranNumber, 1)[0];

        if (randomMsg.length === 0) {
            randomMsg = tmpMsg;
            tmpMsg = [];
        }

    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is very simple, but may keep iterating a lot, specially if the number of messages is low. If there aren't at least two messages, there will be an infinite loop.

```js
var messages = ["string one", "string two", "string three", "string four", "string five"];
var i = -1,
    intro = document.getElementById("intro");
(intro.onclick = function() {
  while( i == (i = Math.floor((Math.random() * messages.length))) );
  intro.textContent = messages[i];
})();
```

```html
<h1 id="intro"></h1>
```

To avoid those problems, better use the following, even if it's a bit less simple:

```js
var messages = ["string one", "string two", "string three", "string four", "string five"];
var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * messages.length)),
    intro = document.getElementById("intro");
(intro.onclick = function() {
  intro.textContent = messages[i];
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * (messages.length-1)));
  i = rand + (rand >= i);
})();
```

```html
<h1 id="intro"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the more readable approach.

```
(function message() {
    var introElem = document.getElementById("intro");
    var randomMessages = [
      "string one",
      "string two",
      "string three",
      "string four",
      "string five"
    ];
    var randomMessagesLength = randomMessages.length;

    introElem.innerHTML = getRandomMessage(introElem);
    introElem.onclick = function() {
        introElem.innerHTML = getRandomMessage(introElem);
    };

    function getRandomMessage(elem) {
        var isNewRandMessage = false;
        var randMessage = "";
        do {
            randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMessagesLength);
            randMessage = randomMessages[randNumber];
            if (elem.innerHTML != randMessage) {
                isNewRandMessage = true;
            }
        } while (!isNewRandMessage);

        return randMessage;
    }
})();
```